# Button behaves differently on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to do a toggle button for the search bar. If the user clicks on the button for the first time, the search bar appears. If the user clicks the second time, and if there is a value (the user has typed) then submit the form.
Else, if the user clicks outside the bar, it closes.

I finished the code for this, and it works fine on Firefox, however it doesn't work on Chrome and Microsoft Edge:

- On Firefox, when you click on different regions of the button, it behaves the same (opens the search bar)
- On Chrome and ME, when you click near the bounds of the button, it opens the search bar, but when you click near the center, it doesn't

I tried to log something when the event click is fired, everything works fine, but the actual result is not that good.

```js
var _sbmButton = document.getElementsByClassName('eti-srch-sbm')[0],
  _input = _sbmButton.etiFindSiblings('eti-frm-t-s')[0],
  _frmAction = _input.parentElement.parentElement,
  _logo = document.getElementsByClassName('eti-logo')[0],
  click = 0;
_sbmButton.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  click++;
  _nav.classList.add('nav-hide');
  _logo.classList.add('logo-hide');
  _frmAction.classList.add('frm-show');
  _input.focus();
  if (_input.value !== '' && _frmAction.classList.contains('frm-show') && click > 1) {
    _frmAction.children[0].submit(); //Check if the searchbar has been opened and the input !== ''
  } else {
    evt.preventDefault(); //Else stop submitting the form
  }
}, false);
document.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  if (target !== _input && target !== _sbmButton) { //Check click outside
    click = 0;
    _nav.classList.remove('nav-hide');
    _logo.classList.remove('logo-hide');
    _frmAction.classList.remove('frm-show');
  }
});
```

```css
.eti-srch-sbm {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 30px;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
}
```

```html
<form name="search-top" method="get" class="eti-frm-t" action="search">
  <input class="eti-frm-t-s" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off">
  <button class="eti-srch-sbm"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Quick guess, but I'm guessing the icon is blocking the click.  Try adding a `pointer-events:none` on it.

Comment: Welcome to the world wide web

Comment: FYI `document.getElementsByClassName('eti-srch-sbm')[0]` is silly. Why search through the entire DOM for elements that match the class name when you know you only want to use the first one? Use `.querySelector()` instead.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yeah, thanks for your advice

Comment: @MatthewJohnson But in FF it still works. It’s kind of weird

Comment: Yeah, browsers have come a long way, but they still behave differently in edge cases.  Did the `pointer-events:none` fix anything?  If not, it might help to update the snippet so that it replicates the issue.  I tried boiling it down to a minimum example, but it's clickable for me.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson, let me have a look

Comment: @MatthewJohnson, it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @WebDegBrian Awesome!  I added an answer stating the fix.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon is blocking the click.  Add `pointer-events:none` to the styles to have clicks "pass through" to the button.

**The CSS**

```
.eti-srch-sbm .fa{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```